# Neo4j - Match only one node/time in loop

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I wonder if it's possible to limit the MATCH to only one node in a Cypher query.

I have billions of nodes, and there's a huge difference if I use Limit 1 in a match or not:

1) `MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.id = "UUID" RETURN n LIMIT 1`

2) `MATCH (n:Node) WHERE n.id = "UUID" RETURN n`

(1) executes in milliseconds, (2) takes few minutes (I believe it's trying to find *all* nodes with that id, despite having a unique index).

Now, in a huge CSV file that has two two nodes IDs, I want to match and create a relation between as follow:

```
PROFILE
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///CSV_FILE.csv" as row
MATCH (n:Node {id: row.`:START_ID`})
MATCH (m:Node {id: row.`:END_ID`})
MERGE (n)-[:RELATION]->(m)
```

This takes ages. I tried adding `LIMIT 1` at the end, and the results are blazing fast, but the loop itself is interrupted after the first row. Doing `LIMIT 2` instead and performances drop to abysmal levels.

**Is there a way to limit each match to only one node?**

Comment: If you have an index/constraint on :Node(id) and the planned, for some reasons is not using it (check it with an `EXPLAIN), you can force the index by `USING INDEX n:Node(id)`

Comment: Thanks for the EXPLAIN and USING INDEX n:Node(id). The result shows one query NodeUniqueIndexSeek with 1 match, the second is NodeByLabelScan with 2B hits ... strange.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using, and can you paste the plan from your EXPLAIN (after expanding all elements of the plan)?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, it's the current latest version, the 3.2.2. Now it seems it searches both with NodeUniqueIndexSeek ... Unsure if the DB was corrupted or not (doing :schema results in "no index", then after few minutes indexes re-appear).